# How to swap items with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing a little program to help me understand pointers better to finish an assignment I'm working on.

Here's main

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

typedef struct some_t {
    int x;
} some_t; 

some_t *i, *j;

i->x = 1;
j->x = 2;

some_t *tmp;

tmp = i;
*i = *j;
*j = *tmp;

printf("i is %d\n", i->x);
printf("j is %d\n", j->x);

return 0;
}
```

As soon as I run it I get a segmentation fault and my emacs gud-gdb won't run through the program. I start it but then says 'continuing until next break.'

What I'm ultimately trying to do is I have a `bag` with pointers to objects (weapons, tools, etc) and a `equipment` struct (objects that are equipped). When I want to equip one of the objects in the `bag` I want to just flip the pointers of the objects. So that the pointers in the `equipment struct` point at the weapon and then the pointer in the `bag` swaps to pointing at what the previous object replaced.

Comment: first allocate memory to your pointers using <code>malloc()</code> and then assign a value.Your pointers are pointing to some invalid location.

Answer (score 1):

`some_t *i, *j` defines two pointers, but they don't point anywhere useful. They are *uninitialized variables*.

Immediately after those definitions you try to dereference these pointers. Since they don't point anywhere meaningful, that's causing your problems. Make sure you point your pointers *at* something before you use them:

```
some_t a, b;
some_t *i, *j;
i = &a;
j = &b;
```

Or something along those lines.

Editorial note: you have a bunch of extra `*` in your swap routine; you just want to swap the pointers, right?

```
tmp = i;
i = j;
j = tmp;
```

Comment: Good practice is to assign the pointers right in the declaration, or set to NULL so dereferencing will fail fast and cleanly.

Comment: Dereferencing `NULL` doesn't (necessarily) cause any more well-defined behaviour than dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. Good point about initializing at definition time.

Comment: You don't ever want to rely on this in production code, but on typical machines dereferencing NULL means 0 which should always be invalid memory, causing an immediate segfault.  However if the pointer happens to refer to "valid" memory than you may not notice a problem right away.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating memory for the pointers to point at. Without this the program doesnt know where pointers i and j are pointing. 
You need to allocate memory first and then make the i and J point to it.

> `i=malloc(sizeof(some_t));  j=malloc(sizeof(some_t));`

Also you are not actually swapping pointers.You are de-referencing them and basically copying data from memory location pointed by j to memory location pointed by i. This is okay but when you do `*j = *i` in the next step you are basically copying same content to memory pointed by j which it already holds.

Comment: I would usually recommend `i = malloc(sizeof *i)` to save some trouble if you change variable types down the road.

Comment: Oh I totally forgot to allocate memory for the two pointers. On to your second point. I see how j is getting the location of itself, how do I do it correctly then? Swap what the two pointers are pointing at.

Comment: Or not the location. We're dereferencing it so it's what it's pointing at.

Comment: I think I get it from other comments. Just re-point the pointers to point at the new object they should be pointing at. `tmp = i; i = j; j = tmp;`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the following:

```
typedef struct some_t {
    int x;
} some_t; 

some_t *i, *j;

i->x = 1;
j->x = 2;
```

Here, you have the pointers `i` and `j` which do not point to any valid memory.
You need to allocate enough memory, then point your pointers to the allocated memory and only then should you store values.

```
typedef struct some_t {
    int x;
} some_t; 

some_t *i, *j;
i = malloc(sizeof(*i));
j = malloc(sizeof(*j));

i->x = 1;
j->x = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dynamically allocate space, but you do need to allocate space. Here is an example where you static allocate space.  It also has the change where you swap the pointers (i and j) instead of swapping the dereferenced pointers (*i and*j):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

typedef struct some_t {
    int x;
} some_t; 

some_t val1;
some_t val2;
some_t *i, *j;

i = &val1;
j = &val2;

i->x = 1;
j->x = 2;

some_t *tmp;

tmp = i;
i = j;
j = tmp;

printf("i is %d\n", i->x);
printf("j is %d\n", j->x);

return 0;
}
```